# customize django admin page with terminal interface

Tags: django, forms

I am trying to customize my admin site in django with a terminal looking template. 
1. What is the action of the form to direct to admin home?
2. My since the page is terminal, pressing enter submits the form, how can I delay till I have the username and password before submitting?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
...
<!-- admin form -->

<form name="adminform" method="POST" action="{% url '???' %}" >
    {% csrf_token %}
    <!-- {{ form.as_p }} -->

    <p class="search__form" >

        login: <input type="text" class="input search__input" id="username" placeholder="" name="search" {{form.username}} autofocus />

    </p>
</form>


<!-- my javascript checks if input starts with a '$' sign then it is the username, if it begins with a '.' it is a password, I want to combine the two and send for admin authentication -->

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: what does it mean "a terminal looking template"? or "the page is terminal"? Can you explain?

Comment: you could add `required` to your `input` tags - please note the current one doesn't make sense

Comment: Terminal looking template is a page that appears like a command line... One instruction executed at a time.

Comment: Actually, the thing is, depending on the input, the terminal should identify a username or a password depending on the first character of the string.